# How to add a View class for a plugin in cakephp 3?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

As the heading to this question states how does one go about adding/integration a View class to a plugin in Cakephp 3?

There is the AppView class for the application but when baking a plugin no View class is included.

Answer (score 2):

There is no View class baked into plugin, because by default plugins are using View class from main application.

If you need to do some specific view-rendering logic in your plugin, you can create eg. `YourPluginDir/src/View/CustomView.php` and do your things there. You need also to tell your controller to use this View class:

```
$this->viewBuilder()->setClassName('YourPlugin.Custom');
```

More info about custom View classes can be found in docs:
[Creating your own view classes in CakePHP](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#creating-your-own-view-classes)